# How can you create an array from the firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From the SDKs you can use the push() call to generate an auto ID, this structure is seen by Javascript as an array. But there appears to be no way to do this same thing from the console. I understand that everything in firebase is essentially an object, even arrays, but how can I at least auto gen an id from the console as push() would do from the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't depend on the console for everything!  You can execute a push using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/).  Once you learn how to use it, it's arguably faster and more powerful than the console.  There's a [lot of things](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/read-and-write-your-realtime-database.html) you can do with it. In that linked blog, there is a section on pushing data with this example:

```
firebase database:push /messages --data '{"name":"Doug","text":"I heart Firebase"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for generating push IDs for the Realtime Database from the Firebase console. It's been requested a few times, and there even was a Chrome extension doing it at some point, but the feature has never been added (and is unlikely to be added in the near future).

Interestingly enough, the console fire Cloud Firestore **does** have the option to generate UUIDs for new documents.